# How to identify pin 1 on component with ambiguous marking - bar and dot

Tags: markings

I have a component in a VSSOP (TXS0102DCU), which I am uncertain of the orientation. There is both a bar and a dot. The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0102.pdf) just specifies pin 1 marking area, but this does not seem clear to me.

Going by the answer to a similar question ([How do I identify Pin 1 on a chip with no corner mark](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48734/how-do-i-identify-pin-1-on-a-chip-with-no-corner-mark)), I would have guessed blue is the right marking. This is based on the orientation of the text. Is this correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: https://e2e.ti.com/support/logic/f/151/t/542870

Pin 1 (green circle) as shown below:

[image]